# Get methods in my subclass are getting errors and i cannot solve them

Tags: java

Here is the primary class (I am trying to build a program to check items in a stock):

```
/**
 * Shows various details of an item.
 *
 * @author Brian Clarke
 * @version 28 sept 2017
 */
public class Item {
  // instance variables
  private String id;
  private String descr;
  private int quantity;
  private double price;
  private double discount;

  /**
   * Constructor for objects of class Item
   */
  public Item(String id, String descr, int quantity, double price, double discount) {
    // initialise instance variables
    id = id;
    descr = descr;
    quantity = quantity;
    price = price;
    discount = discount;
  }

  /**
   * Get and set methods for variables.
   *
   *
   *
   */
  public String getid(String id) {
    return id;
  }
  public String getdescr(String descr) {
    return descr;
  }
  public int getquantity(int quantity) {
    return quantity;
  }
  public double getprice(double price) {
    return price;
  }
  public double getdiscount(double discount) {
    return discount;
  }
  public void setid(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public void setdescr(String descr) {
    this.descr = descr;
  }
  public void setquantity(int quantity) {
    if (quantity < 0)
      quantity = 0;
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }
  public void setprice(double price) {
    if (price < 0)
      price = 0.0;
    this.price = price;
  }
  public void setdiscount(double discount) {
    if (discount < 0 || discount > 0.8)
      discount = 0;
    this.discount = discount;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "Item1{" + "ID = " + id + ", description = " + descr + ", quantity = " + quantity + ", price = " + price + ", discount = " + discount + '}';
  }
  public double computeCost() {
    return (quantity * price - quantity * price * discount); // Normal price minus price by the percentage discount should give the correct discounted price
  }
}
```

And here is the test class where I am getting the errors in the last 5 lines, e.g ( method `getid` in class `Item` cannot be applied to given types; required: `java.lang.String` found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length).

I am not sure how to fix them and have tried editing:

```
/**
 * Test the class Item
 * The code tests all methods in the class Item
 * @author Brian Clarke
 * @version 28 Sep 2017
 */

public class ItemTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create two objects to represent two stock items
    Item item1 = new Item("ZA423", "Refurbished smartphone", 14, 149.99, 0.3);
    Item item2 = new Item("BD015", "New 40' TV", 8, 299.99, 0.8);

    item1.computeCost();
    item2.computeCost();

    item1.setid("ZA423");
    item1.setdescr("Refurbished smarthphone");
    item1.setquantity(14);
    item1.setprice(149.99);
    item1.setdiscount(0.3);

    System.out.println(item1.toString());

    item2.setid("BD015");
    item2.setdescr("New 40' TV");
    item2.setquantity(8);
    item2.setprice(299.99);
    item2.setdiscount(0.8);

    System.out.printf("\nItem2 ID is: %s\n", item2.getid());
    System.out.printf("\nItem2 Description is: %s\n", item2.getdescr());
    System.out.printf("\nQuantity is: %s\n", item2.getquantity());
    System.out.printf("\nPrice is: %f\n", item2.getprice());
    System.out.printf("\nDiscount is: %f\n", item2.getdiscount());
  }
}
```

The code is not complete but this is most of it. I've searched a lot but couldn't find any answers. I am very new to Java and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do your getters require the caller to pass in what they're trying to get? Call me and I'll give you my phone number.

Comment: Tip: you could do `System.out.printf("Item2 ID is: " + item2.getid())` instead of `System.out.printf("\nItem2 ID is: %s\n", item2.getid());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined getter methods incorrectly. In your implementation you expect to pass a parameter to each getter method, which does not make much sense, since getter method is meant to return a value. Instead

```
public String getid(String id) {
  return id;
}
```

you should do:

```
public String getid() {
  return id;
}
```

Remove all parameters from getter methods and it will work.

UPDATE:

<strike>Two</strike> Three more things worth mentioning:

- constructor of `Item` class is incorrect. Assignments like `id = id;` won't work, you should do `this.id = id;` instead (you have to explicitly say that the `id` on the left side is a field in the class and `id` on the right side is a value passed as a constructor parameter)
- when you use a constructor that expects all fields to be passed you can mark all fields as `final` and remove setter methods to prevent an instance of this class from changing its state - this is a good rule worth following
- consider using camel-case notation. If your field name is `id` then getter method should be called `getId` and setter - `setId`. This is a convention widely used in Java programs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice it fixed the errors, and ill use that notation now! I am fairly new to java but was just taught about using 'this.whatever = whatever;'. Hopefully more time and practice will help and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to enter a parameter to getters method because you need to get the Id not set it to a new value otherwise you will get the same value you entered, and which in your case you didn't enter, that's why you're getting the error (missing parameter). Write this code instead so you can get the data you already set before:

```
/**
 * Shows various details of an item.
 *
 * @author Brian Clarke
 * @version 28 sept 2017
 */
public class Item {
    // instance variables
    private String id;
    private String descr;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private double discount;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Item
     */
    public Item(String id, String descr, int quantity, double price, double discount) {
        // initialise instance variables
        id = id;
        descr = descr;
        quantity = quantity;
        price = price;
        discount = discount;
    }

    /**
     * Get and set methods for variables.
     *
     *
     *
     */
    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getdescr() {
        return descr;
    }
    public int getquantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public double getprice() {
        return price;
    }
    public double getdiscount() {
        return discount;
    }
    public void setid(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setdescr(String descr) {
        this.descr = descr;
    }
    public void setquantity(int quantity) {
        if (quantity < 0)
            quantity = 0;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public void setprice(double price) {
        if (price < 0)
            price = 0.0;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public void setdiscount(double discount) {
        if (discount < 0 || discount > 0.8)
            discount = 0;
        this.discount = discount;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Item1{" + "ID = " + id + ", description = " + descr + ", quantity = " + quantity + ", price = " + price + ", discount = " + discount + '}';
    }
    public double computeCost() {
        return (quantity * price - quantity * price * discount); // Normal price minus price by the percentage discount should give the correct discounted price
    }
}
```